# SQL SERVER ODBC ERROR(Invalid object name) but when I add in SQL query mydb.dbo.mytable all works fine

Tags: sql-server, schema, odbc, connection-string

I have an old asp.net 1 project (it works fine on old server, mytable exist in db. Now I am trying to upgrade it to asp.net 4

My connection string is:

```
<add key="SqlConnection" 
     value="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=bel\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_connection=yes;DAT­ABASE=mydb;option=3;"/>
```

I get error

> ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Invalid object name 'mytable'.
>
> OdbcCommand dataCommand = new OdbcCommand("select * from mytable",
>   dataConnection);
>   dataCommand.CommandTimeout = 900;
>   OdbcDataReader dataReader =
>   dataCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

When I wrote SQL as `select * from mydb.dbo.mytable` all works fine

What I should change in db settings (security, schema, dbo) or in connection string?

Comment: Just always specify the schema - e.g. use `dbo.MyTable` instead of just `MyTable` - so try `select * from dbo.mytable` - does that work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My guess, seeing that you're using ODBC, is that your ODBC connection doesn't specify a default database, and so it's using master.

You can either:

- specify the database in your connection string using "Database=myDBname" or "InitialCatalog=myDBname"
- change the default database in your ODBC connection, as shown here in XP/Server 2003 [image: SQL Server ODBC]

Comment: another thing worth trying is toggling b/w `Database` and `InitialCatalog`. I was able to connect to Azure Synapse with `InitialCatalog` but couldn't actually query until I switched the param to `Database`.